# how to write compound REST methods, and REST methods of verbs in spring?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

For example I have UserController with methods:

```
GET /api/users -- get all users
GET /api/users/1 -- get concrete users
POST /api/users -- create concrete users
PUT /api/users/3 -- update concrete users
```

It is classic REST. But I have 2 questions.

1. How should the method look like that makes payment in REST archetecture?

like this? - `POST /api/payments/pay` - But pay is verb

or login of user - `POST /api/users/3/login`???

2. I have 2 controllers - `MarketController` and `CarsController` with methods:

`GET /api/markets/3` -- get market with id = 3

`GET /api/cars/1`    -- get car with id = 1

Client try get concrete car from concrete market:

`GET /api/markets/3/cars/1` -- in which controller should I write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer for the question #1

That's a **misconception**: [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) doesn't care about the URI design. However, once the central piece of the REST architectural style is the [*resource*](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1), it makes sense that the URI that identifies a *resource* contains a *noun* instead of *verb*.

To avoid verbs, you could use just `/api/payments`. A `POST` to that URL will create a payment with the representation sent in the request payload.

For the authentication resource, you could use `/api/auth`, for example.

### Answer for the question #2

It seems to be a method for the `MarketController`, which is mapped to `/markets`.

But keep in mind that your controllers shouldn't perform any business logic. Instead, it should delegate to a service.

Comment: that is, if the user wants to log in this URL POST /api/users/login is correct?

Comment: @ip696 I would simply use `/auth` or `/login`. I don't see the point of sending the id in the URL, to be honest.

Comment: In my honest opinion, I don't fully agree with your first statement. REST doesn't specify anything about the actual format of your URI indeed, but the main point is that your URI should target a _resource_. This rule kind of implies implicitly that a URI shouldn't contain _verbs_ but only _nouns_. I tried to summarise this [here](https://medium.com/qudini-engineering/rest-over-http-or-why-your-http-api-isnt-restful-94fd92a0e6d4#6ebd). Again, I might be wrong. Anyway, just my two cents, and I agree that `POST /payments` is the right approach for a RESTful API :)

Comment: @sp00m You are correct. REST is all about resources. Let me rephrase my first statement.